# Lines that touch same polygon two times in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line

I have lines that touch neighboring polygons. But in some cases line touch same polygons two times, which I do not need.

Thus, I would like to select those line that touch one polygons two times and remove them.

Or, I would like to select lines that touch and connect different polygons.

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1 with python, arcpy library.

I would be happy to have any suggestions to solve the case.

[image]

Comment: That diagram isn't very clear. By "touch" do you mean "touch at a point"? Which lines in that diagram do you want to include?

Comment: Basically, the lines connect the vertices of polygons, as the line represent the Delaunay Triangulation edges. The edges touch neighboring polygons, but at the same time they touch vertices of their own to make a triangulation edges. Thus, I want to remove lines that touch same polygon and keep line that touch neighboring ones.

Comment: You can Intersect lines with polygon with Point as ouput. You should then be able to select in some way to identify duplicate lines.

Comment: If you Intersect with *Multipoint* as the output, then the rows where vertex count is greater than one have multiple connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction, your lines are straight line segments touching one or two polygons (no other case is possible). So you could also use spatial join to get the number of feature that intersect your line, the select those with one single intersecting feature (meaning that they touch twice the same polygon). Below is an example when you right-click on the line layer to launch spatial join, but there is also a tool in the toolbox if you want to make a model or a script.

[image]

As a remark, in your case, selecting all the lines inside the convex hull of the polygons also yields the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines touch the polygons with their ends, then you can use [Feature Vertices To Points](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) to transform line's ends into points. Then use [Tabulate Intersection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm) to count how many points touch the polygon.
[image]

Numbers at the picture are FIDs of each feature type (polygons, points, lines). As you can see in the table `ORIG_FID` field contain lines FID values. Next field `PNT_COUNT` contain number of point that lays on polygon object with FID values in field `FID`.

Comment: But, how can I know from that that a line that touches the same polygon two times from this?

Comment: @peter See update.